# How to handle RMQ connection loss?

Tags: java, scala, rabbitmq, connection

We're using Java RMQ client in Scala and we're experiencing some issues on DEV environment. We have this fallback strategy set up:

```
def addConnectionShutdownListener(connection: Connection): Unit ={
    connection.addShutdownListener { cause: ShutdownSignalException =>
      logger.error(s"Error on RMQ connection: ${cause.getMessage}", cause)

      if (exitOnFail) {
        logger.info("Terminating process with RMQ consumer is shut down")

        System.exit(1)
      }
      else if (retryOnFail) {
        logger.info(s"Retrying to connect")

        retryCreatingConnection(1)
      }
    }
  }

  addConnectionShutdownListener(rmqConnection)
```

In a similar fashion, I added channel connection shutdown listener.

So there are 2 strategies which we use (and modify through config)

- exit on fail
- retry on fail

I set up exit on fail strategy and sometimes it works correctly. I see this line on log when error happens *Terminating process with RMQ consumer is shut down* and service is restarted correctly (kubernetes pod is shut down and it is started automatically again). I disabled RMQ auto recovery because it didn't worked at all.

The problem is sometimes some queues are left without consumers and messages are being queued and hanging, but there is no this error message in log. It's really hard to test it, since I don't know what circumstances happened on our DEV environment.

What could happen?
Is there a better way to handle a connection loss, or to be more precise - to handle a scenario when consumers are somehow detached from queue?

Thanks in advance,

Amer

Comment: "The problem is sometimes some queues are left without consumers and messages are being queued and hanging, but there is no this error message in log" maybe there are no consumers at all? have you checked RMQ monitoring on presence of some activity in the queues? maybe your dev k8s isn't configured right to start corresponding consumers?

after all, I'm leaning towards that problem is not in the connection/channel handlers, but in some other places. perhaps you should add some monitoring to your dev RMQs and detect activities in the queues

Comment: Thanks. That's what we're onto for sure. I just wanted to check if there is some known issue someone faced...